# Automation of salesforce Lightning pages using selenium

Tags: selenium

this question is related to provar automation tool which is used for salesforce automation so can you please let me know about the below comment which i get from from provar official website.

***Generate robust field locators automatically and reuse them across different test environments.They’re designed to be resistant to minor cosmetic changes.***

What does it mean? What kind of minor changes you are talking about? What major changes provar can't handle?

Comment: Please don't address questions to specific members of the community. Clarification about specific non-Salesforce products are typically best addressed to product support.

Answer (score 0):

Any UI automation tool rely on some kind of identifiers in DOM. Tool get elements using those identifiers in REGEX or XPath. So if DOM structure changes the script execution might fail. The statement you mentioned in explaining that prover automatically generate XPath or REGEX automatically which accommodate minor changes at UI level.

Comment: have you ever worked with provar?

Answer (score 0):

If you load up a standard page in Salesforce and inspect the page you will see that each input field (as an example) has an Id which for a standard page is the Id of the field (copy the Id and in classic visit / and you will be taken to the field definition). Now go and look at a Visualforce page and inspect a field. You will again see there is an auto-generated Id that is difficult to decipher.

Knowing this, lets think about how tools such as provar locate fields for testing - using this id within their searches throughout the DOM (the webpage in a structured tree format). What happens if you change the Id? You won't be able to find that same field.

What provar are doing is suggesting an anchor or identifier that is unlikely to change between environments meaning that your tests will all still run.

Comment: can you please let me know how they are making it feasible to locate the web element on both salesforce classic and lightening page using xpath or some other locator.

Comment: Because when i try to locate a element using xpath on classic the same xpath does not work on lightening though i never use id. I always use dynamic xpath.

Comment: You would need to speak to provar support for that. Your question was asking how such a system worked. You will likely need different locators for Lightning and Classic.

Comment: You're welcome, remember to accept answers if your question is resolved to keep things tidy.